# Error with pg_search multisearch after initializing tsearch, trigram

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search, pg-search

I had pg_search working on my Rails 3.2.3 app using multisearch.  Then I implemented the initializer provided by nertzy (author of pg_search) in  [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512642/how-to-enable-tsearch-dictionary-for-pg-search-multi-search).  Now when I run a search I get the following error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text % unknown
LINE 1: ... ((coalesce("pg_search_documents"."content", '')) % 'searchterm...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

My view is rendered with this code:

```
<%= @pg_search_documents.each do |pg_search_document| %>
  <%= pg_search_document.searchable.title %>
<% end %>
```

The rest of my setup can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577178/basic-setup-for-multisearch-in-pg-search-and-rails-3-2-3)  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: Hey John.  I'm trying to recall, but I think I fixed this by removing the trigram functionality (whatever that is).  So deleting this line: `:trigram => {}` fixed it for me.

Comment: Ya, digging deeper I found that you have to install the trigram package for it to work. The pg_search page has a little bit of documentation on it.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this problem before too. Just to clarify for anyone else who might be running into trouble... here's how to install the extension:

1. Create a new migration by running

   ```
   bundle exec rails g migration add_trigram_extension
   ```
2. In your migration, paste the following code:

   ```
   def up
       execute "create extension pg_trgm"
   end

   def down
       execute "drop extension pg_trgm"
   end
   ```
3. Run the migration with `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

This worked for me locally. Some of the extensions or configurations you can use with pg_search require newer versions of Postgres. In order to use certain extensions on heroku, you may need to use a dev database.

UPDATE: It is my understanding that heroku has issued rolling upgrades and now everyone is running a newer version of pg by default. The above should work on heroku without the need to upgrade your database.

Comment: I'm the author and maintainer of pg_search, and what @stephenalexbrowne says is exactly correct. More info is available at https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/wiki/Installing-Postgres-Contrib-Modules

Comment: @nertzy I have followed this to the T and it breaks locally and on Heroku with the `PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text % unknown` error. I'm on the shared DB that offers the trigram package and I have PG installed via homebrew with the trigram package there.

Comment: @Simpleton Usually you would be see something like `text % text`, not `text % unknown`. Maybe you could open an issue at https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/issues and paste in your query?

Comment: Cool, will open an issue later today if I get time.